# WebService returning idented XML

Tags: xml, web-services, indentation

It is standard for a Web Service that returns XML to return it with indentation?

Also, is it standard to have new lines in the XML that is returned, or can it just be without indentation/new lines completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's standard, but generally a webservice will return XML that is not formatted or indented.  XML is intended to be machine readable, so whitespace and formatting is not an issue.  If you need to read the XML yourself there are many tools and browser plugins that will help format it for you.

Answer (score 0):

A Web Service will return what ever it was programmed to return.

Comment: I know that. I was talking about actually implementing a web service, whether or not it was required/needed to have indentation in the XML.